# Error when getting the Title list of all content controls in the shape (Word)

Tags: c#, ms-word, com, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

I want to get the Title of all content controls contained in word document (shapes). I found out some tips on the Internet. But when I run this code, it has an error (in the picture)

[image]

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application) w;
_activeDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument;
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in _activeDoc.Shapes)
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl cc in s.TextFrame.TextRange.ContentControls) {
    MessageBox.Show(cc.Title.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I can assume, that one of Shapes doesn't have TextFrame property or it's null.

Comment: You are right,  Krivitskiy Grigoriy and  Cindy Meister . Thank you so much.